# How to get median of column positive elements in a tensor/matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conditional-statements, distribution, median

Specifically given a 2-D matrix, how to find median for every column's positive elements?

Mathematically speaking: return B, where `B[i] = median({A[j, i] | A[j, i] > 0})`

I know that median can by computed by 　`tf.contrib.distributions.percentile`

`tf.boolean_mask(A, tf.greater(A, 0))` outputs a 1-D list instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.boolean_mask()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) indeed returns a 1-D tensor, as otherwise the resulting tensor with dimensions kept would be sparse (c.f. columns having a different number of positive elements).

As I do not know of any median function for sparse matrices, the only alternative coming to mind is to loop over the columns, e.g. using [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

```python
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.convert_to_tensor([[ 1, 0,  20, 5],
                          [-1, 1,  10, 0],
                          [-2, 1, -10, 2],
                          [ 0, 2,  20, 1]])


positive_median_fn = lambda x: tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.greater(x, 0)), q=50)
A_t = tf.matrix_transpose(A) # tf.map_fn is applied along 1st dim, so we need to transpose A
res = tf.map_fn(fn=positive_median_fn, elems=A_t)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(res))
# [ 1  1 20  2]
```

---

*Note:* this snippet doesn't cover the case when a column contains no positive elements. `tf.contrib.distributions.percentile()` would return an error if its input tensor is empty. A condition on the shape of `tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.greater(x, 0))` could for instance be used (e.g. with `tf.where()`)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the column slices and filter like this.

```
inputlist = [[5 , -10 ] ,
           [10 , 3 ] ,
           [15 , -5 ]]

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=inputlist)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(x.get_shape().as_list()[1]) : #loop over columns
    print( sess.run(tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(tf.gather(x[:,i],
                                                                     tf.where(tf.greater(x[:,i],
                                                                                         0))),
                                                        50.0)))
```